# how can i get text to show in all cards when hovering over with pointer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get all three cards to reveal text when hovering over them with the mouse pointer, however it only shows the text in the first card on the left but not in the other two cards, even when I have already put the lorem ipsom text in all 3 div's for the cards it will not show.

I have looked for solutions online but cant find any thing close to solving it. It appears that I may have to add a JavaScript loop to iterate through it, but I cant figure out how I could do this.

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card" id='card'>
    <div class="orangeCover">
      <p id="hidden" class='easein'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, eaque.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id='card'>
    <div class="orangeCover">
      <p id="hidden" class='easein'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, eaque.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id='card'>
    <div class="orangeCover">
      <p id="hidden" class='easein'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, eaque.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}

.orangeCover {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

.orangeCover:hover {
  background-color: orangered;
  transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}

.card {
  border: 2px orangered solid;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://source.unsplash.com/random/250x250");
}

#hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.reveal {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
let text = document.querySelector("#hidden"), i;
let overlay = document.querySelector(".card");
let hiddenOverlay = document.querySelector(".card");

overlay.addEventListener("mouseover", newOverlay);
hiddenOverlay.addEventListener("mouseleave", hidden);

function newOverlay() {
  text.style.visibility = "visible";
  text.className = "reveal";
}

function hidden() {
  text.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: Your IDs must be unique. Use `class="hidden"` instead and `var text = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");`

Comment: Better yet, don't use ids at all. This is a css-only project and ids are the 30# frozen turkey of specificity (for the 50# beast, see !important).

Answer (score 0):

I removed `IDs` i.e. `hidden` and added them as `classes` in below

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gh08osLn/1/) snippet.